# drone.io: disable/enable builds for some branches

Tags: continuous-integration, processing-efficiency, drone.io

For some projects I use the CI service drone.io. Currently every time I make a commit to any of my branches, drone.io launches a build process. In some situations I consider this a waste of energy and resources and thus want to prevent unnecessary builds. Such situations are e.g.: Changed typos in README.md, working on a new feature and thereby committing some immature code

As far as I know there is no branch-wise configuration. However, [this thread](https://discourse.drone.io/t/how-to-limit-build-concurrency-per-project/3500/9) in the support forum indicates that via the `.drone.yml` some fine tuning seems possible. But still I do not know how to enable/disable builds on branch-level.

Alternatively, using some special tag in the commit message would also work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `where` trigger to target a particular branch only, see [where](https://docs.drone.io/pipeline/triggers/) for the documentation.

Using `where` & `branch` you can trigger drone builds for changes to e.g. master only to cut down on unwanted builds. Try adding a block like this:

```
trigger:
  branch:
  - master
```